# Any way to view unverified contract's source code on Zksync era?

Tags: zksync

Is there any way to view source code of a unverified contract on Zksync era?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately there's no way to do that. There are some tools like https://ethervm.io/decompile that decompile the bytecode into something a little more readable, but it's not great.